# Unbiased estimator of mean of exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, order-statistics

$X_1,X_2, .. ,X_n$ is a random sample of an exponential distribution with mean $\theta$. Show $nX_{(1)}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$

When I calculated $X_{(1)}$, there's a $n$ in the numerator. There's no way $nX_{(1)}$ is unbiased since there's a $n^2$ in the numerator..

Can someone check if the problem is correct and give me links for the relevant formulas (if the problem is correct)?

Comment: The problem is correct.  If you would like help finding your error, you might post your work. (I'm making the mild assumption that $N$ should be $n$)

Comment: Ok, I got the distribution of  $X_{(1)}$ is $ng(x)(\int_{x}^{\infty} g(y)dy)^{n-1}$ which gave $n(1/ \theta e^{-2x/\theta})$ is that correct?

Comment: After a minute of thinking “what in the world is $n$ doing there?” I have come to strongly suspect that your notation $X_{(1)}$ is supposed to represent the **minimum** of those $n$ (most likely i.i.d.?) random variables.

Comment: @Michael Yes $X_{(1)}$ is the minimum.

Comment: I don't actually know what you're solving for there.  Add your detailed work to the original question.  You'll have more leeway in formatting and more space to explain your notation.  For a hint on one method, you can use $$\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(X>x)\,dx$$ for any non-negative random variable $X$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I have not seen that formula before. What I tried doing was find the distribution of $X_{(1)}$ using the formula I mention in comment 2. Then show that $E(nX_{(1)}) = \theta$.

Comment: As best I can guess, you were trying to find the **probability density function** of $X_{(1)}$ and completely forgot about the $n-1$ in the exponent of $\int_x^\infty g(y)\,dy = \mathbb{P}(X_1 > x),$ so the function you've found ($n(1/ \theta e^{-2x/\theta})$) isn't the probability density function of $X_{(1)}$ (in fact, it's not even a probability density on $[0,\infty)$ for $n\neq 2$)

Comment: Yes... looking back now that's what happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distribution of the first (minimum) order statistic $X_{(1)} = \min(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ of an iid sample $(X_1, \ldots X_n)$ drawn from an exponential distribution with mean $\theta$ may be computed as follows.  Consider the survival function of $X_{(1)}$, namely $$\begin{align*}
S_{X_{(1)}}(x) &= \Pr[X_{(1)} > x] \\
&= \Pr\left[ \bigcap_{i=1}^n (X_i > x) \right] \\
&\overset{\text{ind}}{=} \prod_{i=1}^n \Pr[X_i > x] \\
&\overset{\text{id}}{=} \Pr[X > x]^n \\
&= (e^{-x/\theta})^n \\
&= e^{-nx/\theta}. \end{align*}$$  The equality with 'ind' on top holds because the $X_i$ are independent; the equality with 'id' on top holds because the $X_i$ are identically distributed.  Consequently $X_{(1)}$ has probability density $$f_{X_{(1)}}(x) = -S'_{X_{(1)}}(x) = \frac{n}{\theta} e^{-nx/\theta}$$ over the same support as $X$.  It is immediately obvious that $X_{(1)}$ is itself exponentially distributed with mean $\theta/n$; therefore, the expectation $$\operatorname{E}[nX_{(1)}] = \theta$$ as claimed.